# Lambda expression to Iterate through a collection and edit C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

How do I do this using a Lambda expression?

```
foreach (var l in urllist)

{
  l.Url = l.Url + "?id=" + client.id+ "&active=" + client.Active;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, it is `1.Url`

Comment: Oh, maybe that's supposed to be `l.Url` and it's essentially a `+=` operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use Linq to modify collections, use loops instead:

So this is the best approach (have a look at the [`UriBuilder` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx)):

```
foreach (var l in urllist)
{
    l.Url = string.Format("{0}?id={1}&active={2}", l.Url, client.id, client.Active);
}
```

You have to create a new collection otherwise what is less efficient than modifying the original collection:

```
urllist = urllist
    .Select(l => {l.Url = string.Format("{0}?id={1}&active={2}", l.Url, client.id, client.Active; return l;})
    .ToList();
```

If `urllist` is a `List<T>` you could also use the pre-linq .NET 2 method `ForEach`:

```
urllist.ForEach(l => l.Url = string.Format("{0}?id={1}&active={2}", l.Url, client.id, client.Active));
```

Comment: Note, that `.ToList` will actually return a `List<string>`, you'd have to do `.Select(l => { l.Url = ...; return l }).ToList()`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Whoops, corrected. Thanks. However, you should really don't use this approach at all. So i just wanted to prevent it ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I am sticking with conventional foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a `List<T>` you can use the [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method:

```
urlList.ForEach(x => x.Url += "?id=" + client.id+ "&active=" + client.Active);
```

Otherwise, this will work, although it relies on a side effect of the evaluation of `Count`, and I wouldn't recommend it for production code:

```
urlList.Select(x => x.Url += "?id=" + client.id+ "&active=" + client.Active)
       .Count();
```

Personally, I'd stick with a conventional `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
urllist.ForEach(l => 1.Url = l.Url + "?id=" + client.id+ "&active=" + client.Active);
```